# How to remove that useless long page (or how to improve this code)?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I've been working on Shiny RMD for a while, and I always have this kind of kinky issues.
Here, I've got a whole page about the Shiny Session environment, and it bothers me.
Any idea how to remove (or hide)?
Below is my functioning code.

Kindest regards and thanks in advance,

Edit: Thanks to @shafee, I've managed to fix. Code above.

````
---
title: "Lab"
author: "Unknown"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)
```

```{r}
selectInput("Box1","Choose a name", choices = c("All",unique(l$name)))
selectInput("Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(l$age)))
```

```{r}
data1 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    if (input$Box2 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$age == input$Box2),]
    }
  })

    data3 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box2 == "All"){
      data1()
    }else if (input$Box1 == "All"){
      data2()
    }else if (input$Box2 == "All" & input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }
    else{
      l[which(l$age== input$Box2 & l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })
```

```{r}
  observeEvent(c(input$Box1,input$Box2),{

    if(input$Box1 != "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(data1()$age)))
    }

    else if(input$Box2 != 'All'){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(data2()$name)))
    }

    else if (input$Box1 == "All" & input$Box2 == "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c('All',unique(l$age)))
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(l$name)))
    }
  })
```

```{r}
renderTable({
    data3()
  })
```
````

Comment: You didn't assign the last `reactive{}` to any variable, which is creating such long info about the session. Assigning to a  variable would remove all this session info on the shiny app. And it's not clear to me, what the need for that last reactive expression is.  It is look like some thing like `observeEvent` is suitable here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to have dynamic input selection. Order matters.
I've tried oberveEvent, but it bug out. I'm not in pure Shiny, but in ShinyRmd, hence some function works differently.